# ReactJS - Parent Component setState causes child to call constructor instead of componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm relatively new to React and I am trying to get a NavItem Component I have made to tell its child SubMenu to open upon the NavItem being hovered over.

My issue is that I am trying to use CSS transitions to animate the submenu opening. The transitions are inside the child subMenu so I pass in a boolean prop which the parent NavItem will update using setState.

The transitions don't work however as instead of calling componentWillReceiveProps it calls the child constructor again.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleMouseOver = this.handleMouseOver.bind(this);
    this.handleMouseExit = this.handleMouseExit.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        isSelected: false
    };
}


handleMouseOver() {
    this.setState((prevState)=>{
        return({
            isSelected: true
        });
    });
}

handleMouseExit() {
    console.log("Mouse Has Exited");
    this.setState((prevState)=>{
        return({
            isSelected: false
        });
    });
}

render() {
    let sublinksExist = this.props.link.sublinks.length > 0;
    const CBNavLink = styled.li`
        background-color: #777;
        color: white;
        display:block;
        list-style-type:none;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        height: inherit;

        :hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
        }

    `;

    const CBLinkContainer = styled.div`
        height: inherit;

        a {
        height: inherit;
        min-width: 150px;
        color:inherit;
        display:flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        text-decoration:none;

        }

    `;
    const CBNavItemTitle = styled.div`
            min-width: 150px;
            display: flex;
            color:inherit;
            height: inherit;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
    `;

    return (
        <CBNavLink onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseOver} onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseExit}>
            <CBLinkContainer><Link linkDetails={this.props.link}/></CBLinkContainer>
            <SubMenu isOpen={this.state.isSelected} orientation={this.props.orientation} level={0} links={this.props.link.sublinks}/>
        </CBNavLink>
    )
}
```

Can anybody help me figure out what I am doing wrong?
Cheers

EDIT:
Here is the subMenu Component as well.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("SubMenu Constructor");
    console.log(props.level);

    this.state= {
        isOpen: this.props.isOpen
    }
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
        isOpen: nextProps.isOpen
    });



}

render() {

    var translateAmount = this.props.level == 0 ? 0 : 300;

    if(this.props.orientation == "right") {
        if(this.props.level == 0) {
            translateAmount -= 150;
        }
        else {
            translateAmount = -translateAmount;
        }

    }
    const CBSubMenu = styled.ul`
        width: ${props => props.isOpen ? '300px' : '0px'};
        display: ${this.state.isOpen ? "block" : "none"}};
        position:absolute;
        padding-left: 0;
        transition: width 300ms ease-in;
        transform: translate(${translateAmount}px);
        color:#fff;

        @media (min-width: 800px) {
        padding-left:0;
        }



    `;

    const subMenuItems = this.props.links.map((link, index) => {
        return <SubMenuItem orientation={this.props.orientation} level={this.props.level} link={link}/>;
    });

    return(<CBSubMenu isOpen={this.state.isOpen}>{subMenuItems}</CBSubMenu>);

}
```

Every time that I now hover over the navItem it prints "SubMenu Constructor" to the console and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: What your submenu component looks like?

Comment: Have added in the submenu component. Cheers

Comment: Can you create a executable code snippet so that we can check the issue?